# Custom directive not working when using with a third party library (Angular 2+)

Tags: angular

I have a custom directive that is linked in properly, but doesn't seem to work when I am using it with a third party library. I know it's linked in properly because when I use it in the component.html it works fine. But when using it in the component.ts, it doesn't work.

So here's my code:

component.ts:

```
gantt.templates.rightside_text = ((start, end, task) => {
  return `
    <div [icon]="flag" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;"></div>
  `
});
```

`[icon]="flag"`  doesnt work. But if I throw that whole return statement in the html it works fine.

Why is it not kicking in?

I'm using the dhtmlx gantt library. Here's a link to the [library's documentation](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_rightside_text_template.html).

Comment: Probably you will need to give more context, more code, reproduceable example using a live demo way, that can some one try to help you.

Comment: How are you calling this function in html file ?

Comment: @SunilSingh this function is part of a library and runs onInit. the html is just an empty container and gets populated onInit

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is to compile the `Directive` through String value, which is certainly the not way you can achieve in `Angular` today. May be `Angular` support this in future since there many people who are seeking for similar functionality.

#### What is alternative solution ?

1. You can put the `css` `class` instead and customize through `css`. Not a great solution though.
2. You can create the `Directive` which you can put at the very first parent in html and by using `@ViewChild` and `Query Selector`, you can find the element and manipulate as per your requirement.